# Python IRC bot disconnecting after 3 pings

Tags: python, python-2.7, irc, twitch

So i have coded a small twitch irc bot, but its getting disconnected, the bot just stays ponging the pings and after 3 pongs my bot receives 0 data from twitch and disappear from the viewer list.

Here is the code(the important part):

```
readbuffer = ""
while (1):
        readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(4000)
        temp=string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
        readbuffer=temp.pop( )
        for line in temp:
            print line
            elif(line[0]=="PING"):
                s.sendall("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
```

Its a function that is deployed as a thread 2 times with different arguments..

The thing is i see the 2 bots on twitch.tv viewer list at first for around 5 minutes then after 3 pings exactly twitch no longer pings or sends anything.

Ask me for more code if you'd like more information, please.

Comment: Are you sure it's actualy sending any responses/ won't `line[0]` be a single character?

Comment: i will try with if('PING' in line):

Comment: still the same, could it be a problem from twitch side?

Comment: I'm 90% sure that your buffer logic is broken. Please see my answer.

Comment: Don't put answers/comments on answers into the question. If you have a solution, you *can* answer your own question.

Comment: If you're looking for a simple working starting point, try [simple_irc](https://github.com/whereswalden90/simple_irc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe unrelated:

Interpret the socket as a file: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile

```
f = s.makefile()
for line in f:
    print 'Read:', line
    command, arguments = line.rstrip().split(' ', 2)
    if command == 'PING':
         f.write('PONG ' + arguments + '\r\n')
```

That makes so many things so much easier. Please try that and comment if the problem persist.

Comment: trying this now will take some time

Comment: Fix the problem and unleashed the bigger problem.. i get an error the the connection was forcibly closed by software in your host machine t. and connection was aborted by remote host,  error 10053 and 10054 respectively. could be a windows issue

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Windows socket. I program on Linux and *BSD exclusively.